# How could I mock this and make sure to not get back null?

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I have the following class that I want to unit test:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class Service {
    private final WebClient.Builder builder;
    private WebClient webClient;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        searchUri = "/search-uri";
    
        webClient = builder.baseUrl(searchUri)
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();
    }    


    public ResponseSpec search() {
        
        return webClient
          .get()
          .uri(uriBuilder ->
              uriBuilder
                  .path("/search-uri")
                  // alot of query param, not important
                  .build()
          )
          .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
          .acceptCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
          .retrieve();
    }
}
```

This is my test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class ServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
private Service service;

@Mock
private WebClient webClient;

@Mock
private Builder builder;

@Test
public void testSearch() {
    
        when(builder.baseUrl(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(builder);
        when(builder.defaultHeader(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(builder);
        when(builder.build()).thenReturn(webClient); 
        issuerServiceImpl.init();
        
        WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec uriSpecMock = mock(WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec.class);
        WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec headersSpecMock = mock(WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.class);
        WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpecMock = mock(WebClient.ResponseSpec.class);
        
        
        when(webClient.get()).thenReturn(uriSpecMock);
        lenient().when(uriSpecMock.uri(Mockito.any(URI.class))).thenReturn(headersSpecMock);       
        
        issuerServiceImpl.searchIssuers("");
}
}
```

An exception (`NullPointerException`) happens in the line of `.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` because the `uri()` returns null and the code tries to call method `.accept()` on a null object.

I am not let to change the `Service` class. I can change only my test class. Not sure how could I make it to work.

Edit: I made it to work, read answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So actually I changed this:

`lenient().when(uriSpecMock.uri(Mockito.any(URI.class))).thenReturn(headersSpecMock);`

to this:

`lenient().when(uriSpecMock.uri(Mockito.any(Function.class))).thenReturn(headersSpecMock);`

And it works good.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem

```
when(uriSpecMock.uri(Mockito.any(URI.class)))
```

you mocked uri to return something when it receives something that's `URI` class but you're using a lambda function.
The method signature is

```
S uri(Function<UriBuilder, URI> uriFunction);
```

Try changing it to

```
when(uriSpecMock.uri(Mockito.any(Function.class)))
```

Also check this for future use, quite a good article

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mocking-webclient

Comment: If I use it as you said: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from UriBuilder to URI`

Comment: You're right. My mistake. Let me try something on my local, see what's going on. Will come back with an update.

Comment: Instead of using specific URI.class, can u use a generic any(). It should match no matter what

Comment: Also, looking at `uri` s method header, it's something like this 
   S uri(Function<UriBuilder, URI> uriFunction); Which obviously is not a URI. The any() generic should do.

Comment: In that case `The method uri(URI) is ambiguous for the type WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec` :)

Comment: Actually your answer helped me to see what kind of class might be good for it... So I changed it to: `when(uriSpecMock.uri(Mockito.any(Function.class)))` and it is working like this :) I accept your answer but edit your answer please. Thank you for your help.